# How can I identify the model of this enclosure / sub panel?

Tags: wiring, electrical-panel, subpanel

The only label I can see says "UL listed class CTL enclosed panelboard GJ 478042". I know it works with type BR breakers. The breaker in the photo is a brand new Eaton BRN120A1CS (20 Amps, single pole, GFCI+CAFCI) that I just installed. There used to be a Cutler Hammer GFCB250 (50 Amps, 2-pole, GFCI). The panel was installed some time before I moved in, so unfortunately I have no other information to go on.

[image: photo of sub panel]

Comment: No labels on the cover?

Comment: Sadly, the cover is missing. I am trying to identify the panel because I need to source a replacement cover, if possible.

Comment: Just wondering if getting a new similar panel with cover be easier or cheaper.  Imagine power can be turned off for this panel at another location, so easy to replace.

Comment: If it doesn't have a cover, you need to de-energize this Right Now and not turn it back on again until you resolve the cover issue.  This is dangerous in so many ways. You can't run panels without covers; nothing holds the breaker in, so you go to turn it off and it falls out in your hands.

Comment: @Crip659 That would've been good advice *before* OP sunk cost into the fancy breaker. Can't change off Eaton now.  I'd just replace in kind; I don't like plastic enclosures but only due to fire-accelerant issues, and I'm not worried about that on a brick wall lol.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica  By similar, I did mean a panel that the breaker would fit/work/belong.  Probably my bad word choice.

Comment: @crip659 yeah the pinch-point issue is Eaton doesn't seem to offer that unit or one like it anymore.  They do make steel spa panels that compact, but the top entry is via flange (actually would be better in all respects). There is a 2460RNM-A2 variant of that, but it has an arched top, which precludes top entry.  (I bet that was the problem - I bet the top entry leaked).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that this is a plastic box mounted outdoors that accepts Eaton BR breakers, there's really only one thing this *can* be, and that's an Eaton 2460RNM.  That said, it's not clear what *revision* of that base part number it is, so you'll need to talk to a supply house that carries Eaton products and see if they can help you identify the precise revision so you can get the correct cover for it.

Comment: I am beyond impressed with your knowledge of this topic. Sincerely, thank you!

Comment: Brilliant!  So it is an Eaton family. But 2-space panels/spa panels/disconnects like that normally sell for under $20 so I doubt they have any repair parts supply chain for it.